# Finding mean of specific column and keep all rows that have specific mean values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, mean

I have this dataframe.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A','D','M','T','B','C','D','E','A','L'],
                   'id': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,5],  
                   'rate': [3.5,4.5,2.0,5.0,4.0,1.5,2.0,2.0,1.0,5.0]})
>> df
  name  id  rate
0    A   1     3.5
1    D   1     4.5
2    M   1     2.0
3    T   2     5.0
4    B   2     4.0
5    C   3     1.5
6    D   3     2.0
7    E   3     2.0
8    A   3     1.0
9    L   5     5.0
```

```
df = df.groupby('id')['rate'].mean()
```

what i want is this:
1) find mean of every 'id'.
2) give the number of ids (length) which has mean >= 3.
3) give back all rows of dataframe (where mean of any id >= 3.

```
Expected output:
Number of ids (length) where mean >= 3: 3

>> dataframe where (mean(id) >=3)

>>df
  name  id  rate
0    A   1     3.0
1    D   1     4.0
2    M   1     2.0
3    T   2     5.0
4    B   2     4.0
5    L   5     5.0
```

Comment: Shouldn't the mean of A be 3.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for means by all groups with same size like original DataFrame, so possible filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.groupby('id')['rate'].transform('mean') >=3]
print (df)
  name  id  rate
0    A   1   3.5
1    D   1   4.5
2    M   1   2.0
3    T   2   5.0
4    B   2   4.0
9    L   5   5.0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby('id')['rate'].transform('mean'))
0    3.333333
1    3.333333
2    3.333333
3    4.500000
4    4.500000
5    1.625000
6    1.625000
7    1.625000
8    1.625000
9    5.000000
Name: rate, dtype: float64
```

Alternative solution with [`DataFrameGroupBy.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
df = df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: x['rate'].mean() >=3)
```